# Azure.Data.Table cannot initialize TableClient or TableServerClient

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I try to use the new [Azure.Data.Tables](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Azure.Data.Tables_12.1.0/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables) in Unity to connect with my Azure Storage account.
But even in the first step, either to create tableclient or create tableserverclient failed and throw exception, the code:

```
tableAccount = new TableServiceClient(connectionString);
```

or

```
var client = new TableClient(
                            connectionString,
                            tableName);
```

both trigger exception as follows, I also try other authentication methods like Shared Key Signatures, still the same exception:

```
    System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for \'Azure.Data.Tables.TableClientOptions\' threw an exception. ---> 
    System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for \'Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport\' threw an exception. ---> 
    System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.\r\n  at
    System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.get_MaxConnectionsPerServer () [0x00000] in <efff4cb93af94c0c950db61b78368b54>:0 \r\n  at
 Azure.Core.Pipeline.ServicePointHelpers.SetLimits (System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler messageHandler) [0x0001c] in <626cc779b13d418999ef918abad55406>:0 \r\n  at
 Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.CreateDefaultClient () [0x0000b] in <626cc779b13d418999ef918abad55406>:0 \r\n  at
 Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport..ctor () [0x00000] in <626cc779b13d418999ef918abad55406>:0 \r\n  
at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport..cctor () [0x00000] in <626cc779b13d418999ef918abad55406>:0 \r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n  at Azure.Core.ClientOptions..ctor () [0x00000] in <626cc779b13d418999ef918abad55406>:0 \r\n  
at Azure.Data.Tables.TableClientOptions..ctor (Azure.Data.Tables.TableClientOptions+ServiceVersion serviceVersion) [0x00000] in <5b9b26bedd314731972adb66b865bbcc>:0 \r\n  at
 Azure.Data.Tables.TableClientOptions..cctor () [0x00000] in <5b9b26bedd314731972adb66b865bbcc>:0 \r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n  at
 Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient..ctor (System.String connectionString, System.String tableName, Azure.Data.Tables.TableClientOptions options) [0x0008e] in <5b9b26bedd314731972adb66b865bbcc>:0 \r\n  at
 Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient..ctor (System.String connectionString, System.String tableName) [0x00000] in <5b9b26bedd314731972adb66b865bbcc>:0 \r\n  at
 Rimon.AzureStorage.Common.AzureTable+<CreateAzureTableStatic>d__6.MoveNext () [0x00018] in E:\\Rimon\\handhold-development\\Assets\\Rimon\\AzureStorage\\Common\\AzureTable.cs:48
```

Really need some help for this!